# Terminate All QThreads on GUI Close

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I have a PyQT gui that has one gui thread, and 24 "tester threads."  They work fine, but still seem to stay up when I close the gui.  How can I gracefully close the threads to avoid python crashing?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Standard Lib
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import os
import random
import sys
import time
# Third Party
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
# Local Kung Fu
stuff


class SSITesterThread(QtCore.QThread):
    # vars for updating gui using signals
    updateText = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    updateColor = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    updateSN = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, thread_number, port, path, parent=None):
        super(SSITesterThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.delay = random.random()
    def run(self):
        self.ssitester()
    def ssitester(self):
        # stuff



class SSITestSuiteGUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self._threads = []
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        # Init class from template and paths
        self.launch_tester_threads()

    def init_gui_nodes(self, com_ports_list):
        for num, port, in zip(range(1, 25), range(0, 24)):
            label = getattr(self.ui, 'com_{}'.format(num))
            label.setText("COM Port: {}".format(com_ports_list[port]["COM"]))

    def launch_tester_threads(self):
        logging.info("Spinning up threads...")
        for num, com_port_chunk in zip(range(1, 25), self.com_ports_list):
            tester_thread = SSITesterThread(thread_number=num, port=com_port_chunk["COM"], path=self.vc_test_path)
            # get a reference to the associated textbox somehow...
            status_box = getattr(self.ui, 'status_{}'.format(num))
            tester_thread.updateText.connect(status_box.setText)
            status_box = getattr(self.ui, 'status_{}'.format(num))
            tester_thread.updateColor.connect(status_box.setStyleSheet)
            sn_label = getattr(self.ui, 'sn_{}'.format(num))
            tester_thread.updateSN.connect(sn_label.setText)
            sn_label.setText("S/N: None")
            tester_thread.start()
            self._threads.append(tester_thread)
        logging.info("Ready for tests.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test_suite = SSITestSuiteGUI()
    test_suite.show()
    # Close app only when window is closed.
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried implementing this solution: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/metalman/10721983/raw/15c6f115f9918fee7c1b88d0a549d4cc59a5b346/qapplication_about_to_quit_signal.py

But got an error:

```
attributeerror: 'function' object has no attribute '__pyqtSignature__'
```

Thanks for your time.

UPDATE:

Added the suggestion below as:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def stop(self):
    return
```

in my SSITesterThread Class, and it errors out when various "emits" I've used as singals in the thread sudden try to access NoneType objects:

```
File in gui.py, line 75 in tester,
self.updateColor.emit("{}".format(thread_colors.green_alert)
AttributeError: "NoneType" object has no attribute 'green alert'
```

Did the fix work, and this is a new problem?  Because it seems like things still aren't shutting down gracefully.

Comment: What is thread_color? It's hard to diagnose whey something is None when we don't even know what the code is.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear.  The emit is from my QThread, and I believe it hasn't stopped on GUI close since it's trying to process NoneType objects that are normally populated when the thread is up.  Is there a way I could confirm the thread closes, as I admit this is inference on my part.

Comment: you can do thread.wait() to block until the thread finishes.

Comment: That seems like more of a hack around the problem though, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're importing your GUI from a form generated by QTDesigner.  Try this:

```
self.ui.closeEvent = self.closeEvent
```

I believe your problem is that you're editing the wrong QMainWindow instance in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to decorate the `stop` method as a slot.

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def stop(self):
   # do thread cleanup, stop thread
```

Comment: So add your code with the decorator to my my SSITesterThread Class?

Comment: Please see my update.  Did I implement your solution correctly?

Comment: I'm happy to try anything to fix this.  Please help?